# Java - método para verificar se uma String contém determinado caractere

Tags: java

Estou com um problema neste método. Ao que me parece, sempre que o tento usar com alguma String, obtenho `false` para o valor de a, mesmo que a String contenha esses três caracteres. Alguém me pode dizer o que há de errado aqui?

```
 public static boolean VerSeTemLetras (String qqString){
    boolean a;
    int tem_a;
    int tem_b;
    int tem_c;

    if (qqString.contains("a")) {
        tem_a = 1;
    } else {
        tem_a = 0;
    }
    if (qqString.contains("b")) {
        tem_b = 1;
    } else {
        tem_b = 0;
    }
    if (qqString.contains("c")) {
        tem_c = 1;
    } else {
        tem_c = 0;
    }

    a = ((tem_a + tem_b + tem_c) > 2 );

    return a;
}
```

Comment: O propósito é saber se a `String` tem `a`, `b` ***e*** `c` ou é para saber se contém `a`, `b` ***ou*** `c`?

Comment: Da para melhorar bastante seu código, o que você quer saber exatamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que isso é melhor

```
public static boolean VerSeTemLetras (String qqString){
    return qqString.contains("a") && qqString.contains("b") && qqString.contains("c"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean verSeTemAeBeC(String qqString) {
    return qqString.contains("a") && qqString.contains("b") && qqString.contains("c");
}

public static boolean verSeTemAouBouC(String qqString) {
    return qqString.contains("a") || qqString.contains("b") || qqString.contains("c");
}
```